# P5.js updatePixels() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to update each pixel to red, so this is my code

```
const canvasWidth = 800
const canvasHeight = 600

function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
  loadPixels()
  let xoff = 0
  for (let x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
    let yoff = 0
    for (let y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y++) {
      pixels[x + y * canvasWidth] = color('red')
      yoff += + 0.01;
    }
    xoff += 0.01
  }
  updatePixels()
}
```

But the code seems doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pixels` array doesn't hold color values like that. The `pixels` array splits the colors into 4 separate indexes for red, green, blue, and alpha. From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels):

```
var pink = color(255, 102, 204);
loadPixels();
var d = pixelDensity();
var halfImage = 4 * (width * d) * (height / 2 * d);
for (var i = 0; i < halfImage; i += 4) {
  pixels[i] = red(pink);
  pixels[i + 1] = green(pink);
  pixels[i + 2] = blue(pink);
  pixels[i + 3] = alpha(pink);
}
updatePixels();
```

You might find it easier to work with the `set()` function, which takes `x`, `y`, and `color` parameters:

```
const canvasWidth = 800
const canvasHeight = 600

function setup(){
    createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    loadPixels();
    for (let x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y++) {
            set(x, y, color('red'));
        }
    }
    updatePixels();
}
```